# Downloading an animated SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-animate

**Long story short:**

I'm tring to download a Lottiefile, however I need to use it as an SVG, including the animation. Seems like these SVG files don't include their own animation, as it's executed from the browser.

The problem is, I need to include this files into a HTML canvas, and we would prefer to use them directly as fully animated SVG files.

**The SVG content in the HTML looks like this:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1080 1080" width="1080" height="1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <defs>
      <clipPath id="animationMask_4r3zTBBKOp">
         <rect width="1080" height="1080" x="0" y="0"></rect>
      </clipPath>
   </defs>
   <g clip-path="url(#animationMask_4r3zTBBKOp)">
      <g transform="matrix(4.275,1.4287,-1.4287,4.275,1148.5403,2510.2734)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(188,204,215)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(4.4166,-0.9002,0.9002,4.4166,2052.1482,1942.0367)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(142,206,193)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(3.3748,-2.9879,2.9879,3.3748,2550.5771,998.1254)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0.241,0.421)">
               <path fill="rgb(0,193,159)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(1.4287,-4.275,4.275,1.4287,2510.2734,-68.5403)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0.241,0.421)">
               <path fill="rgb(239,124,133)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(-0.9002,-4.4166,4.4166,-0.9002,1942.0367,-972.1481)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(250,184,192)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(-2.9879,-3.3748,3.3748,-2.9879,998.1254,-1470.577)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(252,237,90)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(-4.275,-1.4287,1.4287,-4.275,-68.5403,-1430.2734)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(188,173,204)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(-4.4166,0.9002,-0.9002,-4.4166,-972.1481,-862.0367)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(239,237,210)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(-3.3748,2.9879,-2.9879,-3.3748,-1470.577,81.8746)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(50,146,188)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(-1.4287,4.275,-4.275,-1.4287,-1430.2734,1148.5403)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(246,75,68)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(0.9002,4.4166,-4.4166,0.9002,-862.0367,2052.1482)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0.241,0.421)">
               <path fill="rgb(250,201,0)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(2.9879,3.3748,-3.3748,2.9879,81.8746,2550.5771)" opacity="0.7000000000000001" style="user-select: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
               <path fill="rgb(119,90,166)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0 0 M-267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 C-250.91799926757812,-312.8070068359375 -237.4429931640625,-326.2820129394531 -237.4429931640625,-342.90399169921875 C-237.4429931640625,-359.5260009765625 -250.91799926757812,-373 -267.5400085449219,-373 C-267.5400085449219,-373 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375 -267.5400085449219,-312.8070068359375z"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g></g>
      <g transform="matrix(1.86,0,0,1.86,503.3878,529.4277)" opacity="1" style="user-select: none; display: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,19.684,5.684)">
            <path stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" fill-opacity="0" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke="rgb(246,75,68)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0" d="M0 0 M0,-58.68349838256836 C32.38742446899414,-58.68349838256836 58.68349838256836,-32.38742446899414 58.68349838256836,0 C58.68349838256836,32.38742446899414 32.38742446899414,58.68349838256836 0,58.68349838256836 C-32.38742446899414,58.68349838256836 -58.68349838256836,32.38742446899414 -58.68349838256836,0 C-58.68349838256836,-32.38742446899414 -32.38742446899414,-58.68349838256836 0,-58.68349838256836z" style="display: none;"></path>
         </g>
      </g>
      <g transform="matrix(1.86,0,0,1.86,503.3878,529.4277)" opacity="1" style="user-select: none; display: none;">
         <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,19.684,5.684)">
            <path stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" fill-opacity="0" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke="rgb(250,201,0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0" d="M0 0 M0,-58.68349838256836 C32.38742446899414,-58.68349838256836 58.68349838256836,-32.38742446899414 58.68349838256836,0 C58.68349838256836,32.38742446899414 32.38742446899414,58.68349838256836 0,58.68349838256836 C-32.38742446899414,58.68349838256836 -58.68349838256836,32.38742446899414 -58.68349838256836,0 C-58.68349838256836,-32.38742446899414 -32.38742446899414,-58.68349838256836 0,-58.68349838256836z" style="display: none;"></path>
         </g>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

**And the next second it would look like this: Most of the values are changed...**

Hence it's only possible to grab 1 frame of the animation.

Does anyone know if there's anything we could use to walk around this issue? Is it possible to fully download this files anyhow?

**Example animations:**

https://codepen.io/airnan/pen/GOvebO

Kind regards!

---

Update: this is how we are currently using animated SVG files in our game.

```
Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL = '/public/img/';

Drawing.IMG_SRCS = {
  //explosión y humo
  'explosion': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'explosion.png',
  'smoke': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'smoke.svg',
  //unidad
  'self_tank': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'self_tank.png',
  'self_turret': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'self_turret.png',
  //unidad enemiga
  'other_tank': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'other_tank.png',
  'other_turret': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'other_turret.png',
  //drone
  'drone': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'drone.png',
  'drone_cam': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'drone_cam.png',
  //shield, munición, fondo.
  'shield': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'shield.png',
  'bullet': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'bullet.png',
  'tile': Drawing.BASE_IMG_URL + 'full_map_02.png'
};
```

**Now using it.**

```
if (health < 3) {
    this.context.save();
    this.context.translate(coords[0], coords[1]);
    var smoke = this.images['smoke'];
    this.context.drawImage(smoke, -smoke.width / 2, -smoke.height / 2);
    this.context.restore();
  }
```

**Smoke.svg source:**

```
<svg height="36" width="38" viewBox="0 0 38 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="el_95Z6Shlu0"><style>@-webkit-keyframes el_Wn9FrGLYpM_Animation{0%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}@keyframes el_Wn9FrGLYpM_Animation{0%{opacity: 1;}100%{opacity: 1;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_756G_VUuOVp_Animation{6.67%{opacity: 0.3;}53.33%{opacity: 1;}86.67%{opacity: 1;}97.78%{opacity: 0.7;}0%{opacity: 0.3;}100%{opacity: 0.7;}}@keyframes el_756G_VUuOVp_Animation{6.67%{opacity: 0.3;}53.33%{opacity: 1;}86.67%{opacity: 1;}97.78%{opacity: 0.7;}0%{opacity: 0.3;}100%{opacity: 0.7;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_GnCf73WE5vv_Animation{2.22%{opacity: 0.5;}37.78%{opacity: 1;}91.11%{opacity: 1;}97.78%{opacity: 0.5;}0%{opacity: 0.5;}100%{opacity: 0.5;}}@keyframes el_GnCf73WE5vv_Animation{2.22%{opacity: 0.5;}37.78%{opacity: 1;}91.11%{opacity: 1;}97.78%{opacity: 0.5;}0%{opacity: 0.5;}100%{opacity: 0.5;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_KoL6deJFq48_Animation{6.67%{opacity: 0.2;}8.89%{opacity: 0;}46.67%{opacity: 1;}82.22%{opacity: 0.8;}97.78%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0.2;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@keyframes el_KoL6deJFq48_Animation{6.67%{opacity: 0.2;}8.89%{opacity: 0;}46.67%{opacity: 1;}82.22%{opacity: 0.8;}97.78%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0.2;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_JOJvvi0YXe1_Animation{6.67%{opacity: 0.2;}13.33%{opacity: 0;}37.78%{opacity: 1;}75.56%{opacity: 0.7;}93.33%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0.2;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@keyframes el_JOJvvi0YXe1_Animation{6.67%{opacity: 0.2;}13.33%{opacity: 0;}37.78%{opacity: 1;}75.56%{opacity: 0.7;}93.33%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0.2;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_JXAWQS1YMj_Animation{17.78%{opacity: 0;}26.67%{opacity: 0.6;}71.11%{opacity: 1;}88.89%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@keyframes el_JXAWQS1YMj_Animation{17.78%{opacity: 0;}26.67%{opacity: 0.6;}71.11%{opacity: 1;}88.89%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_gSXGabuDdO_Animation{15.56%{opacity: 0;}17.78%{opacity: 0.7;}62.22%{opacity: 0.4;}82.22%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@keyframes el_gSXGabuDdO_Animation{15.56%{opacity: 0;}17.78%{opacity: 0.7;}62.22%{opacity: 0.4;}82.22%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_ZUJ_k2Djg8_Animation{8.89%{opacity: 0;}15.56%{opacity: 0.7;}51.11%{opacity: 0.65;}73.33%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@keyframes el_ZUJ_k2Djg8_Animation{8.89%{opacity: 0;}15.56%{opacity: 0.7;}51.11%{opacity: 0.65;}73.33%{opacity: 0.1;}0%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0.1;}}@-webkit-keyframes el_vO62sB077X_Animation{0%{opacity: 0.2;}8.89%{opacity: 0.7;}46.67%{opacity: 0.7;}77.78%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0;}}@keyframes el_vO62sB077X_Animation{0%{opacity: 0.2;}8.89%{opacity: 0.7;}46.67%{opacity: 0.7;}77.78%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 0;}}#el_95Z6Shlu0 *{-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;animation-duration: 1.5s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;animation-iteration-count: infinite;-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);}#el_LvWRAsxH8A{stroke: none;stroke-width: 1;fill: none;}#el_Wn9FrGLYpM{fill: #D8D8D8;-webkit-animation-name: el_Wn9FrGLYpM_Animation;animation-name: el_Wn9FrGLYpM_Animation;}#el_vO62sB077X{-webkit-transform: translate(17.05212056762px, 3.9999997076400007px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(17.05212056762px, 3.9999997076400007px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_vO62sB077X_Animation;animation-name: el_vO62sB077X_Animation;}#el_7EjS2hzdoW{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_SWS6Byj9tk{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_ZUJ_k2Djg8{-webkit-transform: translate(17.420201543885px, 4.000000394394999px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(17.420201543885px, 4.000000394394999px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_ZUJ_k2Djg8_Animation;animation-name: el_ZUJ_k2Djg8_Animation;}#el_YK6FBFcIAg{opacity: 0.360714286;}#el_NajeInw5Bj{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_zUd_EHWyLO{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_gSXGabuDdO{-webkit-transform: translate(17.104241687215px, 3.9999997736049995px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(17.104241687215px, 3.9999997736049995px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_gSXGabuDdO_Animation;animation-name: el_gSXGabuDdO_Animation;}#el_y2crCPntCk{opacity: 0.360714286;}#el_Kf32TDLP6a{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_Isolk935P2{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_JXAWQS1YMj{-webkit-transform: translate(15.104241445635001px, 2.000000486944999px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(15.104241445635001px, 2.000000486944999px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_JXAWQS1YMj_Animation;animation-name: el_JXAWQS1YMj_Animation;}#el__V2ipVhCP4{opacity: 0.360714286;}#el_nNv7B8MIU7s{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_K90VGUT4RJY{opacity: 0.2671875;}#el_p9b1nwCSkYm{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_JOJvvi0YXe1{-webkit-transform: translate(15.104241445635001px, 2.000000486944999px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(15.104241445635001px, 2.000000486944999px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_JOJvvi0YXe1_Animation;animation-name: el_JOJvvi0YXe1_Animation;}#el_uk_s6X-mVFQ{opacity: 0.103013393;}#el_Yz8KPPtl56W{opacity: 0.360714286;}#el_jpBL1oH10rD{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_eqs21vWjEQ-{opacity: 0.2671875;}#el_e92aP-OMVOF{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_KoL6deJFq48{-webkit-transform: translate(12.49838246413px, 0.9999997408599981px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(12.49838246413px, 0.9999997408599981px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_KoL6deJFq48_Animation;animation-name: el_KoL6deJFq48_Animation;}#el_oOgJcweAt_A{opacity: 0.103013393;}#el_-T8EVuG4xWe{opacity: 0.103013393;}#el_DB691YvWQcj{opacity: 0.360714286;}#el_jWZD5-8v56C{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_2XVe3LpDsNJ{opacity: 0.2671875;}#el_3PvOe-6us_v{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_GnCf73WE5vv{-webkit-transform: translate(12.208483270479999px, -1.6944000158503059e-7px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(12.208483270479999px, -1.6944000158503059e-7px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_GnCf73WE5vv_Animation;animation-name: el_GnCf73WE5vv_Animation;}#el_CZrg-U0EY-r{opacity: 0.103013393;}#el_r4dbOkmY45V{opacity: 0.103013393;}#el_FhzUdo_w-5L{opacity: 0.360714286;}#el_iwKqhfZhEpi{opacity: 0.653459821;}#el_1m1kuZgXwk1{opacity: 0.2671875;}#el_WRlg6wnMnY7{opacity: 0.512834821;}#el_756G_VUuOVp{-webkit-transform: translate(9.234543623105px, 4.693850002013278e-7px) rotate(20deg);transform: translate(9.234543623105px, 4.693850002013278e-7px) rotate(20deg);-webkit-animation-name: el_756G_VUuOVp_Animation;animation-name: el_756G_VUuOVp_Animation;}#el_3WwhdfBQXWw{opacity: 0.0497767857;}#el_jsOetU7o-uO{opacity: 0.0428571429;}#el_Hg4cdRF5Tmp{opacity: 0.189118304;}#el_arat3jsC06d{opacity: 0.296037946;}#el_8e6gP9dRHRu{opacity: 0.106919643;}#el_iEfEfXBAomF{opacity: 0.157924107;}</style>
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 51.2 (57519) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>Slice</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs/>
    <g id="el_LvWRAsxH8A" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="el_Wn9FrGLYpM">
            <g id="el_vO62sB077X">
                <rect id="el_7EjS2hzdoW" x="0.00579296004" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect id="el_SWS6Byj9tk" x="1.00643662" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_ZUJ_k2Djg8">
                <rect id="el_YK6FBFcIAg" x="2.00708028" y="2.00128732" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect x="0.00579296004" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296" id="el_NajeInw5Bj"/>
                <rect x="1.00643662" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465" id="el_zUd_EHWyLO"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_gSXGabuDdO">
                <rect id="el_y2crCPntCk" x="2.00708028" y="2.00128732" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_Kf32TDLP6a" x="0.00579296004" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_Isolk935P2" x="1.00643662" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_JXAWQS1YMj">
                <rect id="el__V2ipVhCP4" x="6.00708028" y="2.00128732" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_nNv7B8MIU7s" x="4.00579296" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_K90VGUT4RJY" x="0.00321831113" y="4.00257465" width="5.00321831" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect id="el_p9b1nwCSkYm" x="5.00643662" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_JOJvvi0YXe1">
                <rect id="el_uk_s6X-mVFQ" x="0.609258398" y="7.7240802" width="3.99420704" height="3.99420704"/>
                <rect id="el_Yz8KPPtl56W" x="6.00708028" y="2.00128732" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_jpBL1oH10rD" x="4.00579296" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_eqs21vWjEQ-" x="0.00321831113" y="4.00257465" width="5.00321831" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect id="el_e92aP-OMVOF" x="5.00643662" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_KoL6deJFq48">
                <rect id="el_oOgJcweAt_A" x="0" y="9.00579296" width="9.00579296" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_-T8EVuG4xWe" x="14.2646636" y="11.7876059" width="3.99098873" height="3.99098873"/>
                <rect id="el_DB691YvWQcj" x="11.0070803" y="2.00128732" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_jWZD5-8v56C" x="9.00579296" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_2XVe3LpDsNJ" x="5.00321831" y="4.00257465" width="5.00321831" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect id="el_3PvOe-6us_v" x="10.0064366" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_GnCf73WE5vv">
                <rect id="el_CZrg-U0EY-r" x="0" y="9.00579296" width="9.00579296" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_r4dbOkmY45V" x="14.0090113" y="14.0090113" width="9.00579296" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_FhzUdo_w-5L" x="12" y="2" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_iwKqhfZhEpi" x="9.00579296" y="-1.15463195e-14" width="4.00257465" height="9.00579296"/>
                <rect id="el_1m1kuZgXwk1" x="5.00321831" y="4.00257465" width="5.00321831" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect id="el_WRlg6wnMnY7" x="10.0064366" y="1.00064366" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
            <g id="el_756G_VUuOVp">
                <rect id="el_3WwhdfBQXWw" x="0.00434472003" y="11.0043447" width="10.9971035" height="10.9971035"/>
                <rect id="el_jsOetU7o-uO" x="18.3241866" y="15.4331637" width="10.9909887" height="10.9909887"/>
                <rect id="el_Hg4cdRF5Tmp" x="15" y="1" width="5.00321831" height="10.9971035"/>
                <rect id="el_arat3jsC06d" x="12.005793" y="1.00128732" width="4.00257465" height="7.99871268"/>
                <rect id="el_8e6gP9dRHRu" x="8.00321831" y="3.00257465" width="5.00321831" height="4.00257465"/>
                <rect id="el_iEfEfXBAomF" x="13.0064366" y="0.000643662227" width="4.00257465" height="4.00257465"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
<script>(function(){var a=document.querySelector('#el_95Z6Shlu0'),b=a.querySelectorAll('style'),c=function(d){b.forEach(function(f){var g=f.textContent;g&amp;&amp;(f.textContent=g.replace(/transform-box:[^;\r\n]*/gi,'transform-box: '+d))})};c('initial'),window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){return c('fill-box')})})();</script></svg>
```

Comment: What does trigger the animation? If it is SMIL, then grabbing the markup will be enough. If it is javascript (and I guess it is), then you may consider include these scripts inside the svg markup itself, but you may have to twick these a bit so that they are smart enough to correctly target your elements. If it's from css, same as for script. Now, you stated that the end goal is to draw this animated svg on a canvas element. You'll get disappointed, but you can't. Per the canvas2D specs, UAs shall only display the first frame of any animated `<img>`'s content.

Comment: Hi Kaiido! Thanks for the quick response... I'm actually sending SVG elements into the canvas without any problem. As I'm inserting another, house made animations in SVG (made by ourselves), the problem is that our SVGs hold the whole logic of the animation, instead, these ones seems to be javascript dependent.

Comment: You are drawing multiple different svg images right? Not a single animated one? Otherwise, it's a browser bug and you should not rely on this. [Here is the link to the specs.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts%3Acanvasimagesource-3).

Comment: mmm, please allow me a second to take a look. Thanks for informing!!

Comment: @Kaiido, I just updated the entry, including Smoke.svg source, that one is locally hosted, animated, and deployed in the canvas, also seems to be working on Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106

Comment: I was actually thinking the same... is it actually running the Js inside the SVG? It seems to work on Chrome like I said, it's a smoke animation... the smoke it's moving, might it be moving inside an specific area? I'm not an expert in SVG...  I find this odd too in any case.

Comment: Ah no ok... So they don't execute js, *me:feeling released*. That's just CSS animation, and that's just the *non-compliance to specs*  bug I talked about. Nevertheless, **don't rely on it**.  Firefox already complies to the specs here, IIRC IE does too. Chrome & Safari don't yet in this case (they do for animated gif though...), but they may well fix these bugs without any notice in any near future.

Comment: So, when it comes to the specs, we have no option to use an animated SVG inside a canvas? I'll test in Firefox and IE to see how it works... I didn't notice it if it wasn't running.

Comment: You are 100% correct, the animation doesn't longer works in Firefox at this moment (Sep, 2018). I'll need to find another way to use animations inside a canvas. I'll close my own question. 100,000 Thanks Kaiido!

Answer (score 0):

As Kaiido stated, using SVG animations inside a Canvas is against the compliance and it shouldn't be done. At this point I'm trying to use **Canvas Sprites** in order to approach this problem.

https://jlongster.com/Making-Sprite-based-Games-with-Canvas

Hope it helps someone.